# Rearrange rows based on condition alternating?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of rows which I want to rearrange one after the other based on a particular column.

`df`

```
     B/S
0    B
1    B
2    S
3    S
4    B
5    S
```

I have thought about doing a `loc` based on `B` and `S` and then adding them all together in a new `dataframe` but that doesn't seem like good practice for `pandas`.

Is there a `pandas` centric approach to this?

Output required

```
     B/S
0    B
2    S
1    B
3    S
4    B
5    S
```

Comment: so you want S to follow B?

Comment: Do you want to keep the index as shown in your output?

Comment: @Erfan The index is not important.

Comment: @sammywemmy yes. either S to follow B or B to follow S, either is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can achieve this by making smart use of `reset_index`:

```
m = df['B/S'].eq('B')
b = df[m].reset_index(drop=True)
s = df[~m].reset_index(drop=True)

out = b.append(s).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

  B/S
0   B
1   S
2   B
3   S
4   B
5   S
```

---

If you want to keep your index information, we can slightly adjust our approach:

```
m = df['B/S'].eq('B')
b = df[m].reset_index()
s = df[~m].reset_index()

out = b.append(s).sort_index().set_index('index')

      B/S
index    
0       B
2       S
1       B
3       S
4       B
5       S
```